# How to avoid escaping /n on each microservice in the chain? Java

Tags: java, json, string, architecture, microservices

For example, we are getting a json message like this from our partner:

```
{
"message": "Dear client,\nWe'd like to offer you.."
}
```

The partner wants the client to receive the message like this (without newline but with `\n`)

```
Dear client,\nWe'd like to offer you
```

But we have a chain of microservices in our ecosystem and that json goes through 4 or 5 microservices which proccesing it before client can get it. So, our partner should give us `\\\\\\\\n` instead of `\n` in order to client got `\n` in the result. But I'm wondering, is adding 8 backslashes in the source message to escape "`\n`" for every microservice the only way to solve this problem. I think it's not really good solution, because we have to make changes in source message if count of microservices in chain changes (Moreover, we will face he problem if count of microservices in the chain start changing dynamically)? Is there way to use `\n` in source message (from partner) without replacing every `\n` with `\\n` in our microservies?

There is an example how I process the json in one of the microservices:

```
private String replace(String sourceJson, List<String> properties, DocumentContext context) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(sourceJson);

    for (String property : properties) {
        String newValue = Pattern.compile("ABC")
                .matcher(stringBuilder)
                .replaceAll(context.read(property, String.class));
        stringBuilder.replace(0, stringBuilder.length(), newValue);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing to your JSON that makes you think you need to do this.

Comment: I add some new properties and transfer JSON to next microservise in the chain

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of the code you use to do this.

Comment: Don't use string operations on JSON. Use a JSON parser.

Comment: But what if I need to replace some words in json with regex?

Comment: Do the replacements on the value of a field, not on the raw JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of creating a JSON object, turning it into a String and and then back into a JsonObject, adding a property, and turning it back into a String again.

```java
package org.example;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonObject o = new JsonObject();
        o.addProperty("message","foo\nbar");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String stringRep = gson.toJson(o);
        System.out.println(stringRep);
        JsonObject o2 = gson.fromJson(stringRep, JsonObject.class);
        o2.addProperty("newProp", 42);
        String messageValue = o2.get("message").getAsString();
        System.out.println(messageValue);
        String newMessageValue = messageValue.replace("foo", "baz");
        o2.addProperty("message", newMessageValue);
        stringRep = gson.toJson(o2);
        System.out.println(stringRep);
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
{"message":"foo\nbar"}
foo
bar
{"message":"baz\nbar","newProp":42}
```

So you can see the the Java representations of strings contain newline characters, but the JSON representations contain the character sequence `'\', 'n'`.

The maven dependency you need is:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hm, it works. I suppose Gson escapes \n in its implementation, am I right?

Comment: So, it means the only way to deal with my problem is replacing \n with \\n on each microsevice in the chain

Comment: No, Gson will not corrupt the JSON -- as you can see in my example, it converts JSON to a String and back to JSON without affecting the representation of a newline character in the JSON string.

Comment: Yes, I see, but I dont understand why does Gson avoid printing newline in gson.toJson(o) ?

Comment: Because when the value of a String property of a JsonObject which contains a newline is rendered to JSON, the newline is replaced by `\n`. That is one of the rules of JSON.

Comment: Thanks, now I get you. The last question, is it possible to do the same with Jackson?

Comment: Yes, Jackson is very similar to Gson. Any correctly implemented JSON parser would do.

Comment: I have one more question. what if I dont know which of properies in json contains 'foo'? i mean i know only regexes and the replacents, but I dont know where of many properties my targers to replace are(I dont know the path). What should I do? Iterate all properties in json and search  for my targets?Btw, I'm using JsonPath.

Comment: Yes, I think you'll need to do that.